# File not found in docker volume

Tags: linux, node.js, docker, makefile, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to create and run several services. One of the services is a nodeJS project in which I added a Makefile to run some custom build tasks.

That's how I define the service in `docker-compose.yml` file

```
web:
      container_name: web
      image: myApp/web
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: operations/.docker/web/${APP_ENV}.dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8080"
      volumes:
        - ./src/js/web:/var/www/myApp/
      working_dir: /var/www/myApp
      env_file:
        - operations/env/web/${APP_ENV}.env
      networks:
        - myApp_network
```

As you can see there is a volume with an alias to my local filesystem. The Makefile is under the `./src/js/web` directory.

And this is the `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /var/www/myApp
RUN npm i
RUN make -f /var/www/myApp/Makefile build
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/pm2
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2", "start", "dist/server/bin/www.js","--name","web","--log","/var/log/pm2/pm2.log","--watch","--no-daemon"]
```

I had the same setup on my mac book and I manage to build and run the services.

However, I recently tried to run docker compose on linux mint and I get the following error.

```
make: /var/www/myApp/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/var/www/myApp/Makefile'.  Stop.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c make -f /var/www/myApp/Makefile build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I also tried to tried to build the image by removing `RUN make -f /var/www/myApp/Makefile build` and it worked fine. When I entered the container I could see the Makefile sitting in `/var/www/myApp`.

Comment: How would I run make build if I remove it?

Comment: From what I see it is a problem on the makefile. Have a look at [Errors generated by make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html).

Comment: makefile is fine because I can run make build within the container; The problem is when I run it when building the container

Comment: Is this a filename case-sensitivity problem?  Your mac is likely case-insensitive, but linux is prob case-sensitive?